# Symbol or notation for element that precedes all members of an ordered set

Tags: notation, order-theory, tensors

I am discussing an ordered set of all tensors of all orders, which is of course infinite. I need to indicate a placeholder which precedes all members of the set.

**Is there a symbol or notation for the element that precedes all other elements of an ordered set?**

I am tempted to use –∞ but that is wrong because –∞ is really just another 0th order tensor, and in my specific ordering, there are infinitely many tensors that precede –∞.

Comment: It is called the bottom.  Some use 0.

Comment: [Top and bottom ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_and_least_elements): $0$ and $1$ or $\bot$ and $\top$.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Thanks. However 0 is also just another 0th order tensor, and definitely not the first in the set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sounds like an answer to me.